# Why does the naive barycentric hodgestar fail?

Tags: pde, computational-geometry, discretization

The discrete exterior calculus is defined first using circumcentric dual cells, because the primal and dual edges are orthogonal and thus the dual cells are convex. This leads to a diagonal hodge star for 1-forms that is defined as $\star_1 = \frac{|\star\sigma^1|}{|\sigma^1|}$ for a primal edge $\sigma^1$ and a dual edge $\star\sigma^1$, what has many computational advantages.

For barycentric cells, the operators are more complicated, constructions for $\star_1$ are found for example in this [paper](http://iranarze.ir/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/E534.pdf) by Mohamed, Hirani and Samtaney. Their hodge star has no sparse inverse and while they suggest how a sparse inverse could be constructed, it would not satisfy the identity $\star_1\star_1^{-1} = -1$.

The reason for the more complicated constructions is, that the dual edges are no longer orthogonal and are kinked at their intersection with the primal edges.

[image: a barycentric and a circumcentric dual mesh]

(Image by [Jiansong Deng](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Vertices-and-their-control-cells-a-Barycentric-dual-control-cell-of-an-inner-vertex_fig2_5483806))

I am now wondering, why you cannot construct a diagonal hodge star by intergrating over the kinked lines. The relevant identities are

$$
\langle\omega^1, \sigma^1\rangle = \langle\star\omega^1, \star\sigma^1\rangle \\
\langle\text{d}\omega^1, \sigma^2\rangle = \langle\omega^1, \partial\sigma^2\rangle \\
\langle\text{d}(\star\omega^1), \star\sigma^0\rangle = \langle(\star\omega^1), \partial(\star\sigma^0)\rangle
$$

For a circumcentric dual 2D mesh $\star\omega^1$ represents are straight line that connects the circumcenter of two triangles and intersects the center of the primal edge.

In a barycentric mesh it is the combination of two line segments. The first identity should hold by definition, when we construct the hodge star by integrating over both segments. And I think Stokes' theorem should hold when integrating over the whole boundary of a barycentric 2-cell.

Which part am I missing, why you cannot construct a diagonal definition that allows for non-convex boundaries composed of split edges with a kink in the middle?